# Unable to post JSON data using HttpPost

Tags: java, javascript, android, httpclient

I am trying to post JSON data to my API. But after execution I'm getting the following result:

```
{"name":"Corporate","addr":"Unknown","area":"Unknown","cityId":10,"phone":"--","fax":"--","wooqStoreId":1}]

Response 2 >>{"message":"Blank String","result":"Error","resultCode":"RESULT_CODE_002"}
true
```

The first 2 lines show my JSON string and
response 2 is the message I'm getting. It should be a successful message as I'm getting status code 200.

```
public static boolean pushtoAPI(String url, String jsonObject) {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost request = null;
            HttpResponse response = null;
            String postUrl = getHostUrl() + url;

            try {
                    request = new HttpPost(postUrl);


                    StringEntity postingString = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
                    postingString.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                    postingString.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                                    "application/json;charset=UTF-8"));

                    request.setEntity(postingString);


                    request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");


                    String custom_cookie = ConstantUtil.authCookie(ConstantUtil.getLoginJsessionId());
                    request.setHeader("Cookie", custom_cookie);

                    response = client.execute(request);
                    System.out.println("Response 2 >>" + EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
                    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                            System.out.println("true");
                            return true;
                    }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            } finally {
                    request.abort();
            }

            return false;
    }
```

Comment: Show server side coe.

Comment: Why javascript `tag`.

Comment: If you don't mind using external libraries i can show u one hell of an easy way!!!

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/sdk/manage.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView Function(@RequestParam(value = "data", required = false) String dataObj,
                        HttpServletRequest request) {
               if (null == dataObj || (null != dataObj && "".equals(dataObj.trim()))) {
                        return this.createJsonResponseMessage("Error", "Blank String", RESULT_BLANK);
                }
         .....................

        }

Comment: yes i dont mind using external libraries.

Comment: jens i have submitted my server side code . please help

Comment: one thing i found is : at server side , i m getting null data. so when i am doin client.execute(request); it is sending null. but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like its a server side code issue.

Can you show where you are creating this string?

> "message":"Blank
>   String","result":"Error","resultCode":"RESULT_CODE_002"

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/sdk/manage.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView Function(@RequestParam(value = "data", required = false) String dataObj,
                        HttpServletRequest request) {
               if (null == dataObj || (null != dataObj && "".equals(dataObj.trim()))) {
                        return this.createJsonResponseMessage("Error", "Blank String", RESULT_BLANK);
                }
         .....................

        }

Comment: From that snippet of code, it looks to me that dataObj is always going to be null, thus making your response the one you are receiving.

Comment: i would be very thankful to you if you could correct my "if statement" in this dataObj correspond to the jsonstring .I am not able to catch the error

Comment: one thing i found is : at server side , i m getting null data. so when i am doin client.execute(request); it is sending null. but why?

Comment: List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userData", jsonObject.toString()));    rob u are right my dataobject is always giving me null..with this code problem is solved thank you

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Apologies I wasnt much help fixing it :P